# Can a goroutine go to sleep during a fmt.Println call?

Tags: go

I was doing some debugging and had a bit of code like this:

```
go func() {
        if !finished {
                fmt.Println("Writing the data")
                writer.Write(data)
        }
}()
```

The `finished` variable is meant as a guard against writing to a writer that has been closed. However, it wasn't working. It appeared to be getting passed the flag. I determined that the call to Println was yielding the goroutine, which could allow the writer to be closed after checking the flag but before attempting the write. Sure enough, removing the call seems to have fixed it. However, I wanted to verify, and more importantly ask for suggestions on how to avoid this properly, rather than just avoiding prints in there.

Comment: Have you run the Go race detector?  Data Race Detector: https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html

Comment: You must use some proper synchronisation and you must _never_ rely on a goroutines being or not being scheduled.

Comment: Well that was essentially my question. I've done plenty of threading in C, but most of the async stuff I've worked on is in JavaScript, which does make guarantees about scheduling. Do you have a recommendation for a nice primer on proper synchronization in go?

Comment: @peterSO, thanks for the suggestion. I wasn't aware of the race detector. I'll definitely start using it. Looks like it already detected another race in the project.

Answer (score 1):

Any I/O, yes, including `fmt.Println`, can cause a pause in goroutine execution.

But in practice, this shouldn't matter, as on any modern hardware, with more than one CPU core, you can experience a race even if the goroutine isn't paused.

You should *always* make your code concurrency safe.

Comment: Well that's assuming that it's running on multiple cores. The important part of my question is what's the idiomatic go way of protecting something like a writer within a goroutine?

Comment: No, there's no assumption--the multiple cores case is explicitly stated.

Comment: There are many ways to avoid it. Use a mutex. Use a channel. Don't use goroutines. The best approach depends on your application, but you haven't provided enough context to offer such a suggestion.

Comment: Where did I state that I planned to run this on multiple cores? In many common concurrent systems (JavaScript, Python, etc), applications will be running on a single core, and code like I provided in my question would be perfectly safe. As a beginner in go, I'm trying to take what I already know, and see where go fits in and what the proper way to do things is.

Comment: Your second comment is the actual answer to the question: basically go is like C/C++, and you should use the same techniques you would use there.

Comment: If my second comment is the answer to the question, then the question is wrong, because the question is "Can a goroutine go to sleep during a fmt.Println call?"  Maybe you would like to clarify your question.

Comment: "and more importantly ask for suggestions on how to avoid this properly, rather than just avoiding prints in there"